# Flex 4.5 , How to create generic skinning library and dynamically change the theme of my AIR application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flashcatalyst

I'm working on enterprise level AIR application, i need to change my application UI for multiple clients,it has a complex UI with more that 250 MXML skin files for all display objects such as buttons, combo box, containers, etc., Is it possible to create a generic skin library for managing skins and assets through CSS or i have to create a separate library for each of the clients?

Currently i'm duplicating the skin files for each client and changing the color values (styles) in CSS (which is the default.css for skin library) and Path data in skins.

Is there any easy way to create a skinning themes in flex 4.5 and managing assets(icons, fxg) in library?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create a custom theme

I suppose you already know this, but creating a custom theme is simply a matter of:

- creating a custom skin for every component
- creating `defaults.css` file to assign those skins and perhaps provide some additional styling information
- making sure that css file is included in the swc
- applying the theme with the `--theme` compiler flag (or through whatever means your IDE provides)

### Applying different colour schemes

You can use `chromeColor` and some other predefined styles to address this issue, but this approach may prove limiting. I solved this by substituting the Spark skin base classes with my own more elaborate versions. There's too much code to paste here, but it comes down to this:

I created an interface like this:

```
public interface IColorizedSkin {

    function colorizeBorder(color:uint, lowLight:uint, highLight:uint):void;
    function colorizeBackground(color:uint, lowLight:uint, highLight:uint):void;
    function colorizeShadow(color:uint):void;

}
```

and I implemented this interface in my custom versions of:

- SparkSkin
- SparkButtonSkin
- ColorizedItemRenderer

These three functions are called from an overridden `updateDisplayList` and use custom CSS style names like `chromeBorderColor` (which is an array of colours that expresses the base colour, the lowligth colour and the highlight colour of the border of a component).
All skins that need colorizing extend these base classes.

The `defaults.css` in the theme library comes with a default colour scheme, but you can override it by adding another css file with different colorizing directives to the client application.
Note that since these custom style names were not added as metadata to the components, you will only be able to assign these colours through CSS or through ActionScript, not through MXML attributes.

### Colorizing icons

If you have an icon set that uses sufficiently neutral colours (for instance all icons are dark grey, or perhaps a grey gradient), you can colorize these too.
The simplest approach which works for solid colors is something like this:

```
    if (iconDisplay) {
        var colorTrans:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
        colorTrans.color = getStyle("color");
        iconDisplay.transform.colorTransform = colorTrans;
    }
```

If you need something more finegrained, you'll have to work with a transform matrix.

### Using different icons

I wouldn't bake icons into the skins, because that would reduce flexibility. I tend to include icons in the library swc, so one can access them from there.
If you need different icon sets for different client applications, simply create a swc including only these assets (i.e. no compiled code) for each set. As long as the names and paths inside those swc's are the same, you should be able to substitute one for the other.

Comment: thank you.I have one doubt using icons from SWC(Embeded library assets) is better or shall i convert my assets to SWF ? Which one will minimize my application size and increase performance ?

 In my application the workflow goes like **Photoshop->Illustrator->Flash Catalyst->Skins** so i'm using most of my skin elements from catalyst, am i doing wright? But i'm facing issues in re-sizable components. i think i need to rework all my skin files to make it as resizable and have to replace my path datas by Rect(primitives).

Comment: **And one more Question:**
      Can i create and position my components and layouts from external XML is that will make sense for configuring my app UI structure ? if so how can i achieve that?

Comment: 1/ I put them in swc; I have no experience with putting them in a swf. 2/ I have no experience with Catalyst (which is no longer being developed anyway), so can't help you there. 3/ Why would you want to do that (external XML)? I can't think of a good reason, unless I don't understand you correctly.

Comment: hum i got your point. I thought to use XML is some client may want the username and password form at the top-right corner of the app and some other may fell better if they have that at center.So i thought to configure that without modifying the inside the view(AS/MXML) that's the reason and nothing else... But i feel that it makes the app more complex.

Comment: Indeed. You'd better store user preferences as simple values (like the position of your login box) and use those values to change the view accordingly. Alternatevely for more complex different layouts, you might want to create multiple skins for the same view and then store the chosen skin as a preference.